# Order the same column by ascending or descending dependant on the value of another column

Tags: sqlite

I've got a situation where I want to order a column by ascending or descending based on the value of a second column (in essence, if column A is odd, sort column B ascending, otherwise descending). Example:

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 4 |
| 2 | 5 |
| 2 | 6 |
| 3 | 7 |
| 3 | 8 |
| 3 | 9 |

would be sorted to

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 6 |
| 2 | 5 |
| 2 | 4 |
| 3 | 7 |
| 3 | 8 |
| 3 | 9 |

Is this even possible in a single SQL query, or would I have to solve this outside of the database? I've got roughly 60 different A-values, so writing a separate query for each possible A-value isn't a viable option.

I tried using "ORDER BY b if (A%2=1, ASC, DESC)", which (unsurprisingly) didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your particular case it is probably easiest to map b, for odd values of a as:

```
select a, b from t 
order by a, case when a%2=1 then 1 else -1 end * b
```

Slightly more compact and cryptic:

```
order by a, coalesce(nullif(a%2=1,0),-1)*b
```

For types where such mapping is not possible in any simple way (say string), another option is to "short-cut" either the asc or desc ordering as:

```
order by a
 , case when a%2=1 then '0' else b end 
 , case when a%2=0 then '0' else b end desc
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/cdPtSDUA)